# Touching the notification closes main application

Tags: android, notifications, back-stack

I want to open downloaded file by notification click. Here's my inent:

```
Intent intent = IntentUtils.getOpenFileIntent(task
    .getTargetFolder()
    + File.separator
    + task.getFileNode().getName());
TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
    .create(App.getContext());
    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = taskStackBuilder
    .getPendingIntent(0,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Everything works (my file opened in appropriate application) but if I touch the notification while my app is active it closed and new application starts working. When I press back-key I don't get back to my application.
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of your problem is that `addNextIntentWithParentStack(...)` should be `addNextIntent(...)`.

The former will resolve stack entries for the app handling the Intent (not your app), defeating your started objective.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that I create TaskStackBuilder from application context?